# How to show a progress bar while uploading a file to google drive

Tags: google-api-php-client

I'm writing a php code which allows to upload a file to our GSuite Drive, it works well.

To go further, I'd like to add a progress bar while the file is uploaded to Google. I've seen some solutions on the web to create a bar with JS while the file is uploaded to my server, but i've no idea how to do it while the file is uploaded to google.

If anyone has an idea, I'd be very interested.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It' me again :p

I've finally used [Dropzone.js](https://www.dropzonejs.com) and the response of the server to show a loading gif, issue solved